# Load text table into Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to load the data from a text file into a table in Java. The first row consists of the column headers, followed by the actual data. I have made it to the point where I could load it all in and read the entire text file, but am new to Java and struggling to proceed.
My question is: What would be the best way to load the table and make it readable by row, rather than the entire file?

```
Name~Job~City~State
Jim~Manager~New York~NY
Fred~Clerk~Philadelphia~PA
Rhonda~Associate~Tampa~FL
```

The code that I have is the following

```
public void readData() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cars.txt"));

    String line;
    while((line = in.readLine()) !=null){
        System.out.println(line);

    }

    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Check this https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/ I believe you can specify the "separator". Then its just like reading any other CSV file.

Comment: Does that work for .txt files? It was my understanding that it wouldn't.

Comment: Have a look at Java's RandomAccessReader or look into Apache's commons libraries

Comment: Do I need to do anything special to get it to read the first row as a the headers then the following as just data or will Commons handle it?

Comment: @jd219 yes it does, after all a CSV file is a text file too

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question - are you asking how do you process the string that represents a single row, or are you asking how do you get one row at a time?

If the latter, then you would just want to remove the loop.  Instead have a method that reads a single row and returns the string representing that rows data.  This method could return a null or an exception at your preference if there are no more rows to be read.  Then the rest of your program operates on that row - probably splitting it into the component parts using something like a string tokenizer.  You would also need a method to open the file and read the column headers.  Are the columns fixed to always be same in your problem domain or can they vary?

If the former, you could use a CSV file reading framework, or you could use a java StringTokenizer class to split the string up into parts based on the separator in the file.

Answer (score 0):

There you are reading the text line by line , thats means how the model of text file your app writing the text like it!If your text file written like this :

### Name ----  Job ---- State

John---------     Driver ------- NewYork

Ammy-------     Engineer---- California

when u get the text with this code :

`while((line = in.readLine()) !=null){ 
  System.out.println(line);
  }`

thats mean at the end of each row pass down a line and you will get it like this model.If you want to read it word by word use "StringTokinaizer" :

```
String text = "This is text, split by StringTokenizer";
    StringTokenizer stknz = new StringTokenizer(text );

    System.out.println("---- Split rows by space ------");
    while (stknz .hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(stknz .nextElement());
    }
```